# change src of <iframe> with javascript

Tags: javascript

What I would try is to change `src="url"` via JavaScript inside the iframe but seems didn't work

the iframe

```
<iframe id="cta" src="http://site1.com/37046"  opacity="0" scrolling="no" margin-top="50px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" align="middle" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="160px">
</iframe>
```

JavaScript code

```
var w = window.top.location;
if(w.host !=='http://originaldomaine.com' && Math.floor(Math.random() *101) < 100){
   document.getElementById("cta").src = 'http://site2.com/59870';
}
```

The purpose is if the the domain doesn't match the original, the js code will call `id="cta"` to replace it with the site2

Comment: Which src you want to change? Within an iframe, do you need to change another iframe's src or the top window's src?

Comment: no the src within an iframe like I mention above

Comment: Please try my answer below

Comment: What do you mean about didn't work ? is the iframe src changed all the time?

Comment: well the code work as a charm when I use `w.href='http://site2.com/59870';}` instead of `{
   document.getElementById("cta").src='http://site2.com/59870';
}`

Comment: So you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var loc = 'http://site2.com/59870';
document.getElementById('sorror').src = loc;
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML (it needed a small syntax fix)

```
<iframe src="http://site1.com/37046"  id="sorror" opacity="0" scrolling="no" margin-top"50px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" align="middle" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="160px">
</iframe>
```

JS

```
var frame = document.getElementById('sorror');
frame.src = "http://site2.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `loc.host` on left and without `http://` on right side (or) combine it with `loc.protocol` as below.

```
var loc = window.top.location;
if(loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host !== 'http://originaldomaine.com') {
   document.getElementById("cta").src='http://site2.com/59870';
}
```

Comment: Where is the 'cta' exists? same iframe or in top window?

Comment: the same iframe

Comment: still doesn't work, maybe the <iframe>  doesn't support call function ?

Comment: @Sergiosanta call function?

Comment: I just mean `Id=cta`

Comment: can you place the html inside the iframe?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what do u mean, please read this article to know more about my purpose [link](https://ppcmode.com/warden/)

Comment: the script redirect  redirect the whole site, in my case I need just to redirect src inside the iframe not the whole site

Comment: It will redirect just the iframe whose id is `Id=cta`. Until you give full html, we can't suggest anything. You have to give the html where the `Id=cta` element exists.

Answer (score 0):

> but seems didn't work.

I guess that you mean your iframe `src` always chaging to site2 because:

1. `w.host !=='http://originaldomaine.com'` always `TRUE`, because
   `location.host` doesn't include protocol (`http(s)://`).
2. Also `Math.floor(Math.random() *101) < 100` in almost time will be `TRUE`. because `Math.floor(0.99999999999999994 * 101) === 100`.

So your if conditions never be `FALSE` and your iframe always changing `src`.

```
    var w = window.top.location;
    if(w.host !== 'originaldomaine.com' && Math.floor(Math.random() *101) < 100){
     document.getElementById("cta").src = 'http://site2.com/59870';
    }
```

Extra point: use `sandbox` attribute in iframe to disable runninig scripts and avoid redirecting.

```
<iframe src='a.php' sandbox></iframe>
```

Comment: there is a misunderstanding here, what Im looking for is if anyone use my script/template in his domain the `src=site1.com` will change automaticly to `src=site2.com` via calling the `id=cta`